# In flexbox css, I am already using justify-content to position the nav elements, how to make space around?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, styles, css-grid

this is a question I have been searching for. I am using justify-content: flex-end already just to have the nav links sit at the end of the main axis. But now I also want to use the space-between property that I usually do to space apart items in a container. The thing is, that I already declared the justify-content with the flex-end value. Is there a more conventional way to do this or have I been doing this wrong the whole time. Please see below for code and picture.

[image]

```
// Nav
import React from "react";


const NavBar = () => {
    return(
        <div>
            <nav>
                <ul className="nav__list">
                    <li className="nav__item">Home</li>
                    <li className="nav__item">About</li>
                    <li className="nav__item">Donate</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    )
}

export default NavBar;


// CSS

.nav__list {
  color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: space-evenly;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to space the links apart. I usually achieve this with the justify-content: space-between. But here, I already used justify-content for something else

Comment: How about using margin-left on each item?

Comment: Yea, I am aware of this. Just wanted to know if there was a more conventional way to do this rather than utilizing margins

Comment: @kennyman335 If you're not going to use margins I'm not sure what you're trying to do. It's the easiest way to get the intended result, so if you're looking for a solution with more steps, you're only making it more complex unnecessarily? You could align the .nav__list to the right, give it a fixed width (with enough space for all the items + extra space) and then apply a `justify-content: space-between;` on the .nav__list, but again, it just seems more work than necessary.

Comment: I got you. Thank you for your response. I just wasnt sure if there were any other flexbox methods to use when the justify-content property is already taken by another value. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave out `align-items: space-evenly;` because it doesn't do anything in this situation.

To achieve the result you want, you can keep the `justify-content: flex-end;` to align everything to the right and then give each child (.nav__item) a `margin-right` except for the last one.

That is what `.nav__list > li:not(:last-of-type)` does, and it reads as follows:
Target every `li` under the parent element `.nav__list`, except for (`:not`) the last of this type (`(:last-of-type)`).

```css
.nav__list {
  color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.nav__list > li:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav__list">
            <li class="nav__item">Home</li>
            <li class="nav__item">About</li>
            <li class="nav__item">Donate</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```